# Conditions for a closed subset to admit an open neighborhood to which it is homotopy equivalent

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I asked a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3959975/do-closed-connected-subsets-of-manifolds-always-admit-open-neighborhoods-to-whi) about whether a closed, connected subset $C$ of a manifold $M$ admits an open neighborhood $U$ such that $C$ and $U$ are homotopy equivalent. The Hawaiian earring shows that this is false, as pointed out in the comments and answers.

But I'm hoping that there are still some conditions, mild if possible, to impose on $C$ such that such a neighborhood does exist. If $M$ is a smooth manifold and $C$ is a submanifold, then the tubular neighborhood theorem gives such a $U$. But being a submanifold is quite a strong condition.

Comment: You may be interested in the weaker but related concept of a "neighborhood retract": https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/neighborhood+retract

Comment: A subcomplex in a CW complex always has this property.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: In general ANR is not enough for a existence of a homotopy equivalent $U$, e.g. consider wild spheres and wild arcs in 3-space.